# How to tell opendmarc to stop using opendmarc-import?

Tags: configuration, opendmarc

I'm running `opendmarc` with `postfix` under Debian linux. I did the standard Debian apt-based install of `opendmarc`, but later, I realized that it is apparenly configured by default to make use of `opendmarc-import` in order to save import data in a database.

I don't want to make use of the database, but I can't find any way to tell `opendmarc` to stop logging info into that database.

I see nothing in `/etc/opendmarc.conf` which seems to control whether or not `opendmarc-import` is configured to be utilized.

Could someone point me to instructions on how to tell `opendmarc` to stop using `opendmarc-import`? I can't find any documentation anywhere that I have searched.

Thank you very much in advance.

**PS**: I guess I could just manually put an `exit(0);` near the top of the `/usr/sbin/opendmarc-import` perl script (or make some other appropriate change to that script), but I prefer not to rely on a hack like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that the `opendmarc` installation seems to have installed periodic runs of `/usr/sbin/opendmarc-import` and `/usr/sbin/opendmarc-reports` into `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`.

All I needed to do is `crontab -e` as root and then comment out those `crontab` entries.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the dbconfig script to help you create a database? You neither need to install that, nor need to opt-in on package installation. Review installed packages named `dbconfig-` and your debconf settings for the `opendmarc` package.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I could play with the `apt` and `debconf` settings and then re-install `opendmarc`.  But I just now discovered another way to fix this. I'm about to write my "Answer" to explain the solution.